# Best Practices -- Constructors and Setters

Tags: java

I have an IDE which I can use to automatically create constructors and setters for instance variables, but I was wondering if the way that it creates them is possibly not best practice. Here is what it does:

```
private String partNum;
private String partDesc;
private int quant;
private double price;

public Invoice( String partNum, String partDesc, int quant, double price )
{
    this.partNum = partNum;
    this.partDesc = partDesc;
    this.quant = quant;
    this.price = price;
}
```

It's the 'this.name' thing that I'm worried about, as well as the constructor labeling the parameters the same names as the variables it's constructing. The setter also does the same thing -- uses a parameter name that's the same as the name of the variable it's setting, and uses this.name.

So, is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: Why don't you just test your methods and see for yourself?! (Anyhow: the code is perfectly correct.)

Comment: Just a standard Java boilerplate. Other JVM based languages are helping, but that's pretty much everything you'll get in Java.

Comment: Why would anything be wrong with that? Does it compile? Does it run? If ain't broken, don't fix it!

Comment: If this is java, I think it's fine.

Comment: @sdir, the methods work fine in the small beginner's projects I'm doing, I'm just wondering if there's any long-term problems that having setters and constructors that are set up like this might cause

Comment: Nah, it's just there to save time, since constructors, getters and setters are always the same thing to write...;)

Comment: It's less confusing than having to figure out a different name for the parameter even if the field and the parameter are so strongly related. There are other alternative conventions to handle this, but this one is fairly common in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are witnessing is pretty standard Java practice, and is even mentioned in the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#14.4.3):

> If a name declared as a local variable is already declared as a field
>   name, then that outer declaration is shadowed (§6.3.1) throughout the
>   scope of the local variable. Similarly, if a name is already declared
>   as a variable or parameter name, then that outer declaration is
>   shadowed throughout the scope of the local variable (provided that the
>   shadowing does not cause a compile-time error under the rules of
>   §14.4.2). The shadowed name can sometimes be accessed using an
>   appropriately qualified name.
>
> For example, the keyword this can be used to access a shadowed field
>   x, using the form this.x. Indeed, this idiom typically appears in
>   constructors (§8.8):

```
class Pair {
        Object first, second;
        public Pair(Object first, Object second) {
                this.first = first;
                this.second = second;
        }
}
```

> In this example, the constructor takes parameters having the same
>   names as the fields to be initialized. This is simpler than having to
>   invent different names for the parameters and is not too confusing in
>   this stylized context. In general, however, it is considered poor
>   style to have local variables with the same names as fields.

When local variables to a method have the same name as class variables, they effectively 'shadow' or hide those variables. But you can still access the class variables by referring to them via the `this` context scope.

Answer (score 3):

That is my preferred way. Otherwise, you would have to think of different arbitrary names for the input parameters and that turns into a hassle.

Answer (score 1):

No there's nothing wrong. The `this` keyword resolve the ambiguity because it tells the compiler that the l-value you are setting is the member variable(es. this.partNum) and not the input parameter(partNum).

If this is a bad practice, that's more a matter of personal taste. Some people don't like to use the same name for both the member variable and the input parameter. Personally I've use this often for several reasons:

- avoid proliferating of names
- Eclipse start autocompleting the name if it starts with `"this."` :)

Answer (score 1):

No. that is not at all a problem. These are just variable names. The lvalue and rvalue are going to maintain their uniqueness.